# Get Path of Gallery Image Android Xamarin and ues it in System.Drawing.Bitmap("path")?

Tags: android, xamarin

I try use this code

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if((requestCode == m) && (resultCode==Result.Ok)&&(data !=null))
            {
                string ni = GetPathToImage(data.Data);
               /// string img = GetPathToImage(data.Data);
                System.Drawing.Bitmap imge = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ni);

            }
```

and use this permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but I get this error

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' threw an exception.
```

Comment: you can't use System.Drawing.Bitmap on Android.  Android has it's own graphics API, Android.Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Android does not use the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` it has its own Graphics API that you should be using instead which `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` so in your scenario it would be something like this:

```
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Graphics;
```

And then use it something like this in the `OnActivityResult` method:

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if((requestCode == m) && (resultCode==Result.Ok)&&(data !=null))
        {
           var  imageUri = data.Data;
           Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, imageUri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks G.hakim  but I want use system.Drawing.bitmap

Comment: May I ask why because this seems unusual!